# Problem with installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 (Windows 8.1 UEFI, two disks- SSD and HDD) on Lenovo Y580

Tags: installation, boot, uefi

I have bought a Lenovo Y580 laptop with an HDD disk. I bought SSD disk too and installed Windows 8.1 64bit on it. Now I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 64bit on the HDD disk, but it seems to be impossible. I turned off fast startup and secure boot, but the problem still exists. I tried  booting from LiveCD and pendrive. Result is always the same. Ubuntu installer dosn't start. Could anybody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you try to do, and what happens?

Comment: I'm trying to install Ubuntu on HDD alongside Windows 8.1 (it is on SSD), but I can't boot LiveCD and ubuntu installer. When I boot LiveCD I can only see 3 illegible rectangles next to each other. When I use Enter or an arrow screen is getting black and nothing happens. Windows is installed in EFI mode and I'm traing to install Ubuntu in EFI mode too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having video problems with GRUB in EFI mode. The simplest solution is likely to be to perform a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation of Linux and then switch the boot mode by installing [the EFI-mode boot loader of your choice.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/)

Installing Linux in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode is fairly straightforward: Use the firmware setup utility to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy support (the exact wording and location of the option varies from one EFI to another), boot the installer in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, and install normally. (For simplicity with the next step, do *not* create a separate `/boot` partition.) The result will probably be that you'll be able to boot Linux but not Windows; but if you disable BIOS/CSM/legacy support you'll be able to boot Windows but not Linux. A caveat: Some computers have quirky EFIs that can cause additional problems. These are too numerous to enumerate, but they're individually rare, and most are easy to overcome. Thus, if you have problems, post back with details.

If you get to this point, I recommend you prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (That page has download links for both types of media.) You can then set your firmware to boot in EFI mode and boot from the rEFInd medium. This should enable you to boot either Linux or Windows. If that works, you can then install whatever [Linux EFI-mode boot loader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) (ideally with boot manager features) you like. If rEFInd worked for you, it should be a safe and easy choice: Just ensure that your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is mounted at `/boot/efi` and install the Debian-package version. GRUB 2 or Fedora's patched GRUB Legacy should work with few problems, too, although if my initial diagnosis is correct, there's a chance that GRUB 2 will produce a corrupted display.

Comment: I forgot to mention that before rectangles appear I can see "Secure boot not enabled" for a very short time. When I turn on secure boot I can see a few lines of tekst, but I'm not able to read it. Result is the same.

Comment: The "secure boot not enabled" message (or another message saying that Secure Boot is *not* enabled) comes from shim, which is what Ubuntu uses to deal with Secure Boot. Neither message denotes an error, and shim shouldn't be causing the types of problems you're describing, so I don't think this information really adds anything new.